# Export descriptive statistics by group from R to LaTeX without exceeding width

Tags: tables, r

I am trying to reproduce, in LaTeX (Overleaf), a table of summary statistics divided by country-year.

The table I got is exceeding width and I can't solve it with solutions I've seen in other questions here or in other forums. Below is the code for the table exceeding width. Would there be any way of having it breaking columns and starting a whole new part of the table with the remaining Country-years? My real data has even more country-years than that.

```
\documentclass[
        12pt,               
    openright,          
    twoside,            
    a4paper,            
    english,            
    french,             
    spanish,            
    brazil              
    ]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{lastpage}           
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{microtype}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\hline
Summary Statistics Table for the Gapminder Data Set & ARG_2015 (N = 1406) & BRA_2002 (N = 2514) & BRA_2006 (N = 1000) & BRA_2010 (N = 2000) & BRA_2014 (N = 3136) & CHL_1999 (N = 1173) & CHL_2005 (N = 1200) & CHL_2009 (N = 1200) & FRA_2002 (N = 1000) & FRA_2012 (N = 2014)\\
\hline
\bf{Conhecimento} & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~\\
\hline
~~ mean (sd) & 1,405; 0.35 $\pm$ 0.29 & 0.50 $\pm$ 0.35 & 0.59 $\pm$ 0.29 & 1,999; 0.48 $\pm$ 0.25 & 3,124; 0.19 $\pm$ 0.24 & 0; NaN $\pm$  NA & 1,194; 0.85 $\pm$ 0.26 & 1,197; 0.49 $\pm$ 0.40 & 0.49 $\pm$ 0.28 & 2,011; 0.45 $\pm$ 0.32\\
\hline
~~ median (Q1, Q3) & 1,405; 0.50 (0.00, 0.50) & 0.67 (0.33, 0.67) & 0.67 (0.33, 0.67) & 1,999; 0.33 (0.33, 0.67) & 3,124; 0.00 (0.00, 0.25) & 0;  NA ( NA,  NA) & 1,194; 1.00 (0.67, 1.00) & 1,197; 0.50 (0.00, 1.00) & 0.33 (0.33, 0.67) & 2,011; 0.50 (0.25, 0.75)\\
\hline
~~ min & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & Inf & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
~~ max & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -Inf & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
~~ Missing & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 12 & 1173 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3\\
\hline
\bf{Population} & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~\\
\hline
~~ mean (sd) & 7.28 $\pm$ 0.00 & 9.07 $\pm$ 0.00 & 13.37 $\pm$ 0.00 & 12.31 $\pm$ 0.00 & 0.42 $\pm$ 0.00 & 11.61 $\pm$ 0.00 & 18.00 $\pm$ 0.00 & 7.49 $\pm$ 0.00 & 7.19 $\pm$ 0.00 & 0.03 $\pm$ 0.00\\
\hline
~~ median (Q1, Q3) & 7.28 (7.28, 7.28) & 9.07 (9.07, 9.07) & 13.37 (13.37, 13.37) & 12.31 (12.31, 12.31) & 0.42 (0.42, 0.42) & 11.61 (11.61, 11.61) & 18.00 (18.00, 18.00) & 7.49 (7.49, 7.49) & 7.19 (7.19, 7.19) & 0.03 (0.03, 0.03)\\
\hline
~~ min & 7.27983820530003 & 9.0691721405 & 13.3688332656 & 12.3130505024 & 0.420588274400036 & 11.6114849984 & 18.0004356286 & 7.4901184544 & 7.18576082240001 & 0.0300030000999874\\
\hline
~~ max & 7.27983820530003 & 9.0691721405 & 13.3688332656 & 12.3130505024 & 0.420588274400036 & 11.6114849984 & 18.0004356286 & 7.4901184544 & 7.18576082240001 & 0.0300030000999874\\
\hline
~~ Missing & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments; instead edit your question to include the fragment in a compilable document that people can play with. Two comments off the top of my head: remove the `|` in the table; such lines are rarely necessary. (Read the `booktabs` documentation). Secondly, you can't possibly require that many significant digits in any number. So round off those numbers to something that makes sense, and you will automatically save lots of space.

Comment: Also, you have underscores in your table headings which won't work since `_` is only usable in math mode, so these need to be escaped with \. And you probably don't need all the horizontal lines either. You mention other solutions on the site, but without linking to any specifically. There are *lots* of similar questions on the site, so it's not clear what about those solutions don't actually help solve your problem.

Comment: One final comment. If you're generating the table from R you should be using an R package to generate nicer tabular material within R, e.g. `Hmisc` or `xtable`. See [How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25575) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here and since I've seen many other questions where the fragment of code is there and no one complained, I didn't even think that would be an issue. What should I do, put it with ```\documentclass``` , etc before? BTW, I didn't put any links because I got lost in so many similar questions that didn't address my specific problem, didn't know for example WHERE to apply other solutions in my own code.

Comment: On the number of digits, you are correct that I don't really need them. Will figure out a way to reduce but that won't solve my issue here since I have many country-years anyway. And yes, this is an output from an R package . It was done with `qwraps2`, the closest I've found so far to turn this big summary into a LaTeX table). I've tried many others (arsenal, psych, etc.). This one easily gave me a descriptive statistics table, the only problem is the width.

Comment: Yes, you can wrap the code in `\documentclass{...}\begin{document}...\end{document}` and load any package that is crucial to run the fragment (in your case, none).

Comment: One last thing: the `|` I should remove are the ones in the head `(`\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}`? Should it turn to something like `(`\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}` to get to something better?

Comment: Just in case I added packages and all that is in the head of my original document, even though I don't think it impacts the table and my issue here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120143/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-guilherme-pires-arbache).

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the table into two parts as shown in the following example allows it to fint onte a single landscape page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\caption{Summary Statistics Table for the Gapminder Data Set}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{wl{2.8cm}}}
\toprule

& ARG\_2015  & BRA\_2002  & BRA\_2006 & BRA\_2010 & BRA\_2014   \\
& (N = 1406) &  (N = 2514) & (N = 1000) &  (N = 2000) &  (N = 3136)   \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\textbf{Conhecimento}}\\
 mean (sd) & 1,405; 0.35 $\pm$ 0.29 & 0.50 $\pm$ 0.35 & 0.59 $\pm$ 0.29 & 1,999; 0.48 $\pm$ 0.25 & 3,124; 0.19 $\pm$ 0.24 \\
 median  & 1,405; 0.50  & 0.67 & 0.67  & 1,999; 0.33  & 3,124; 0.00    \\
   (Q1, Q3) & (0.00, 0.50) &  (0.33, 0.67) & (0.33, 0.67) & (0.33, 0.67) &  (0.00, 0.25) \\
 min & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 max & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
 Missing & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 12 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\textbf{Population}}  \\
 mean (sd) & 7.28 $\pm$ 0.00 & 9.07 $\pm$ 0.00 & 13.37 $\pm$ 0.00 & 12.31 $\pm$ 0.00 & 0.42 $\pm$ 0.00 \\
 median  & 7.28 & 9.07  & 13.37  & 12.31  & 0.42   \\
(Q1, Q3) & (7.28, 7.28) &  (9.07, 9.07) &  (13.37, 13.37) &  (12.31, 12.31) &  (0.42, 0.42) \\
 min & 7.27983820530003 & 9.0691721405 & 13.3688332656 & 12.3130505024 & 0.420588274400036 \\
 max & 7.27983820530003 & 9.0691721405 & 13.3688332656 & 12.3130505024 & 0.420588274400036 \\
 Missing & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\midrule
%Summary Statistics Table for the Gapminder Data Set 
&  CHL\_1999  & CHL\_2005  & CHL\_2009  & FRA\_2002  & FRA\_2012 \\
& (N = 1173)  & (N = 1200) & (N = 1200) & (N = 1000) & (N = 2014)\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\textbf{Conhecimento}}\\
 mean (sd) &  0; NaN $\pm$  NA & 1,194; 0.85 $\pm$ 0.26 & 1,197; 0.49 $\pm$ 0.40 & 0.49 $\pm$ 0.28 & 2,011; 0.45 $\pm$ 0.32\\
 median  &  0;  NA  & 1,194; 1.00  & 1,197; 0.50  & 0.33  & 2,011; 0.50\\
   (Q1, Q3) &  (NA,  NA) & (0.67, 1.00) &  (0.00, 1.00) &  (0.33, 0.67) &  (0.25, 0.75)\\
 min & Inf & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 max & -Inf & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 Missing &  1173 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\textbf{Population}}  \\
 mean (sd) &  11.61 $\pm$ 0.00 & 18.00 $\pm$ 0.00 & 7.49 $\pm$ 0.00 & 7.19 $\pm$ 0.00 & 0.03 $\pm$ 0.00\\
 median  & 11.61  & 18.00  & 7.49  & 7.19  & 0.03 \\
(Q1, Q3) & (11.61, 11.61) &  (18.00, 18.00) &  (7.49, 7.49) & (7.19, 7.19) &  (0.03, 0.03)\\
 min & 11.6114849984 & 18.0004356286 & 7.4901184544 & 7.18576082240001 & 0.0300030000999874\\
 max &  11.6114849984 & 18.0004356286 & 7.4901184544 & 7.18576082240001 & 0.0300030000999874\\
 Missing &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```